# Hibernate Error indexing: null when checking if row exists

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to check if a row exists in my database.

```
Word word = (Word) session.createQuery("select 1 from Word w where w.content = :key").setParameter("key",words[i]).uniqueResult();
```

I'm also trying:

```
Word word = session.get(Word.class,contentId);
```

Besides that I tried session.load,and some others. Everytime Hibernate returns error: 
`Error indexing: null`
or
`Error indexing: no row with the given identifier exists`.

It is true, row does not existing but why doesn't it just returns null like it should for `session.get`:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable).
In case of not finding a row I wanted to create one and add to a database but I'm not able to check if it exists.

---

EDIT:
Word.java

```
public class Word {

    private String content;
    private Set<Sentence> sentences;

    empty constructor, setters and getters
}
```

Word.hbm.xml

```
<class name="Word">
    <id name="content" column="wordId" type="string">
    </id>
    <set name="sentences" inverse="true">
        <key><column name="wordId"/></key>
        <many-to-many class="Sentence" column="sentenceId"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

Sentence.java

```
public class Sentence {

    private long id;
    private ProcessedUrl processedUrl;
    private List<Word> words;

    empty constructor, setters and getters
}
```

Sentence.hbm.xml

```
<class name="Sentence">
    <id name="id" column="sentenceId">
            <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="processedUrl" column="processedUrlId" not-null="true"/>
    <list name="words">
        <key>
            <column name="sentenceId" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <list-index column="idx" />
        <many-to-many class="Word">
            <column name="wordId" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-many>
    </list>
</class>
```

Comment: can u attach your Word class code with annotations or hbm file ?

Comment: `Session.load()` will never return null, because it precisely consists in returning a non-initialized proxy, assuming that the entity exists. Calling load() to check if a row exists doesn't make sense.

`Session.get()` does return null if the entity with the given ID doesn't exist. 

`Query.uniqueResult()` also returns null if the query doesn't return anything.

This is all specified in the documentation. So, read it, and if you're stuck with some code, post the relevant code, and post the complete stack trace of the exception. Trying random things without reading the doc doesn't help.

Comment: I added my code @javaguy

Comment: @JBNizet I can't post complete track trace as I am only getting:
`Hibernate: select word0_.wordId as wordId1_3_0_ from Word word0_ where word0_.wordId=?
Error indexing: null`
on the output from Hibernate.
I know what session.load() returns as well as what session.get() returns that's why I don't understand why Hibernate stops with the error instead of just returning null.